Assumptions checks for Mixed ANCOVA in R
I'm attempting to run a mixed ANCOVA using the lmer function, see computation below:
mixed_model <- lmer(Slope ~ Condition * Time + Age + mA + (1|Subject), data = slope_long)

As a note: Slope is my DV. Condition is my between-subject IV and Time is my within-subject IV. My covariates are Age and MA, which are continuous and collected within-subjects. If the above computation doesn't reflect this, I'd appreciate the feedback.
My main concern is running the assumptions in R - I'm struggling to find resources that address assumptions for mixed ANCOVAs, this is what I have currently:
# 1. Normality of Residuals
residuals <- residuals(mixed_model)
qqPlot(residuals)
shapiro.test(residuals) 

# 2. Homogeneity of Variances
leveneTest(residuals ~ Condition, data = slope_long) 

# 3. Linearity
plot(slope_long$Age, residuals) 
plot(slope_long$mA, residuals) 

# 4. Independence of Observations
# Plot residuals against Time
plot(slope_long$Time, residuals, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Residuals", main = "Residuals vs. Time")

# 5. Homogeneity of Regression Slopes
summary(lmer(Slope ~ Condition + Time + Condition * Time + Condition * Age + Condition * mA + Time * Age + Time * mA + Age * Condition * Time + mA * Condition * Time + (1 | Subject), data = slope_long))

# 6. Absence of Multicollinearity
cor_test(slope_long[c("Age", "mA")])
plot(slope_long$Age, slope_long$mA, xlab = "Age", ylab = "mA", main = "Age vs. mA")

vif(mixed_model) 

Are these correct? My biggest concern is the test for Homogeneity of Regression Slopes, as I don't know which interaction terms I need to include?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

This is a mixed model. ANCOVA is a name for a specific type of regression model. But it's just a regression model, with regression model assumptions. This is a mixed model, with mixed model assumptions.  Each of those assumptions is quite complex, but you can find lots of information by searching this site.
